# NuxtJs nuxt-link not working when parsed through props

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a template which receives data and renders as html and I would like to use component like the `<nuxt-link />` which would allow navigation without reloading the page. Find my code below.

```html
<template>
 <div v-html="content"> </div>
</template>
<script>
 export default{
   name: 'MyComponent',
   props:{
     content: {
       type: String,
       default: ''
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

I then call it in the parent as follows

```html
<template>
  <my-component :content="content" />
</template>
<script>
 export default{
   name: 'ParentComponent',
   data(){
     return {
       content: `Click <nuxt-link to="/login">here</nuxt-link> to login <div>Just some random tex</div>`
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

content gets rendered as html but the `nuxt-link` component is not working. Please how do I go about with this

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that, v-html its used to render pure html components(like divs, inputs, etc..), in your case you wanna render a virtual vue component(nuxt-link), in this case i recomend to see [Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) to generate virtual DOM based in a string

Comment: OP should not generate DOM like that anyway but use dynamic components or render functions.